# Are there any IRC clients that comply with the human interface guidelines?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation

Is there any IRC client that's compliant with elementary's [human interface guidelines](https://elementary.io/docs/human-interface-guidelines)? If not, is anyone trying to build one?

Note that I'm asking for an [IRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat) (Internet Relay Chat) client, not a general purpose chat client that supports 10+ chat services.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good suggestion is probably the IRC client **[Relay](https://github.com/agronick/Relay)** currently in development by agronick and specifically aimed at elementary OS.

You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:agronick/relay
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install relay
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Is there one? Maybe, I'll get to that after the second part. Is anyone trying to build one?

Yes - from [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/2dkpad/chat_application_in_freya/).

> Tom Beckmann is working on a chat plugin for Gala.
>
> Here's a mockup by Daniel Fore. http://danrabbit.deviantart.com/art/Chat-Bubbles-405110826
>
> Here's the code for it [https://code.launchpad.net/~tombeckmann/gala/plugin-chat](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Etombeckmann/gala/plugin-chat) Still in early development.

The mockup:

[image]

Does one exist? Well, [here's the code](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Etombeckmann/gala/plugin-chat) for that one.

I don't have time to read the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://elementary.io/docs/human-interface-guidelines), but from those mockups I'd say Google Hangouts is similar with the floating bubbles:

[image]

[Here is a newer post](http://lmelinux.net/2014/11/25/chat-bubbles-may-come-elementary-os-plank-extension/).

Comment: I wonder: Why and how is that a Gala plugin and not just a "normal" app? And is the project actually still active and usable?

Comment: @quassy The reason for it being a Gala plugin was to have a smoother interaction with notifications. As in, these bubbles can easily re-arrange or dodge. However, now that we're introducing the notifications indicator, we have a lot to consider as far as changing notifications behaviors

Comment: I think you mean FB Messenger? Google Hangouts does not have floating bubbles. P.S. WRT answer quality - this answer doesn't say whether this fits the HIG or not. Maybe someone can confirm?

Comment: @RolandiXor No hangouts is now floating: http://www.pocketables.com/images/2014/10/New-Hangouts-Chrome-app-608x368.jpg

Comment: @Tim is that on ChromeOS/Chrome only? I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: @RolandiXor That's the Google Chrome desktop app, and I'm on Ubuntu but it runs on anything Google Chrome runs on.

Comment: Floating Hangouts also works on Windows.

Comment: Yes, anything Google Chrome runs on.